# Combine 2 Ajax functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, post

I know this question is sort of "stupid", but i tried to combine some variables from inputs and a file upload. I have 2 different ajax calls and want to combine them.

I worked a lot with jQuery and Javascript, but I just cant solve this simple problem.

My html:

```
<div class="slide-new">
        <h2 class="red"><span class="fa fa-floppy-o"></span> Event erstellen</h2>
        <div class="new-content">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" value="" id="new-slide-title">
            <textarea id="new-slide-text" placeholder=""></textarea>

            <form method="post" id="fileinfo" name="fileinfo" onsubmit="">
                <input type="file" name="file" required />
            </form>

            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="button edit-slide-new">
                    <span>Hinzufügen</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My JQuery:

```
function manageSlidesService(slideId, title, content, action) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        url: '/js/ajax/slide.php',
        data: {'slideId': slideId, 'title': title, 'content': content, 'action': action},
        success: function (msg) {
            if ($(msg).filter('.success').html() == 'success') {
                //refresh();
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.responseText)
        }
    });
}

function submitForm() {
    console.log("submit event");
    var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
    fd.append("label", "WEBUPLOAD");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/js/ajax/slide.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: fd,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log("PHP Output:");
        console.log( data );
    });
    return false;
}
```

I call manageSlideService() and submitForm() when I press the save button.

Please do not only give me a tipp how to solve this, also show me a working solution.
Thanks :)

Comment: Why can't you just use single function with joined parameters?

Comment: because this does not work. as you can see above, the second ajax call includes "data: fd". in the other call there are defined post indexes in combination with jquery variables. Its not that simple to join them...

Comment: Put `submitForm()` in the `success` method of `manageSlidesService` and only call `manageSlidesService` when you press the save button. That should do it.

Comment: How about `$.extend({'slideId': slideId, 'title': title, 'content': content, 'action': action}, fd);`?

Comment: @Justinas how can I use this ?